# how to change external partner user role in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

Mistakenly for the partner user wrong role has been assigned
but I tried some steps as follows:

1)Log in to Salesforce
2)Navigate to User Managemen
3)Locate the User
4)Edit User
5)Change the User's Role
6)Save Changes

still not able to update the role for partner users?
anyone can help me out with this?
thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you go user -> contact and move that contact to the account with name that matches the role you want? From what I remember for community the roles are assigned in such indirect way, created on the fly the moment first contact for "this" account is promoted to community user

Comment: Hi, I tried this but didn't work. thank you!

Comment: bummer. I don't have partner community available at the moment to experiment, only customer community plus and with person accounts so assigning contact to different account is out of question... Try asking on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. Worst case you may have to disable this user (break the link between contact and user), obfuscate the user so you can reuse same email, create fresh user with right role... that'll be new password though, new welcome email etc etc...